# Difference between two Grafana panels singlestat and graph with same query

Tags: time, influxdb, grafana

I have created the following Grafana dashboard:

[image]
The **singlestat panel** uses the following query:

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM "rails.pageviews" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

And the **graph panel** uses the exact same query:

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM "rails.pageviews" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

---

How do I make the single-stat panel show the total amount of pageviews? It should be 12 (8+2+2) and not 4, right?

---

When I debug the data returned from Influxdb:

```
response:Object
  results:Array[1]
    0:Object
    statement_id:0
    series:Array[1]
      0:Object
      name:"rails.pageviews"
      columns:Array[2]
        0:"time"
        1:"sum"
      values:Array[73]
        0:Array[1530870900000,null]
        (...)
        37:Array[1530882000000,null]
        38:Array[1530882300000,8]
        39:Array[1530882600000,null]
        (...)
        44:Array[1530884100000,null]
        45:Array[1530884400000,2]
        46:Array[1530884700000,null]
        (...)
        53:Array[1530886800000,null]
        54:Array[1530887100000,2]
        55:Array[1530887400000,null]
        (...)
        72:Array[1530892500000,null]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the singlestat panel defaults to `Average` instead of `Total` (which I expected to be default).

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, but changing the stat to Total didn't work for me, what exactly is your query?

Comment: My query became `SELECT sum("value") FROM "rails.pageviews" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)` and then I did as in this reply set the `Stat = Total`.

Comment: thanks! this works, my issue was I was applying the sum when my fields have string values.

Comment: I'm pleased that it helped you! Happy graphing!